# SUMIF pairs of data with XOR conditional

Tags: excel, sumifs

I'm racking my brains about how to do this and after numerous trials using SUMIF, arrays, SUMPRODUCT, I was unable to get near any solution so I'm hoping someone can assist.

Given the data below I would like to have a sum at the bottom of each "Week" column that totals up the values for each item in the first column of that week.  The catch is that it should only count the value for each item once by either taking the Actual or Forecast if they are available (but never both). If both are available the Actual should be used over the forecasted figure.

The bottom row indicates the correct total for each column and what I would like to have a formula for that calculates this.

Note that due the structure of the sheet I need to do this without a helper column and the items may not always be added in the right order (i.e it could go Actual, Forecast, Actual, Forecast) . Furthermore there will be up to 50 unique items so I really need a more general formula that would work for many items.

```
                 Week1  Week2   Week3   Week4   Week5
Item1   Actual    500    0       100    0   
Item2   Actual    400   100             0   
Item1   Forecast  200   200      300             200
Item2   Forecast  100    0                       100

                  900    100     100    0        300
```

Comment: Why 300 for Week2? 0 is same as blank? Shouldn't it be 100? Why 400 for Week3? There is not data for Item2 and both entries for Item1, shouldn't it be 100?

Comment: If you are stuck with this data structure, then I would use a VBA solution. But if you can change the data structure you would be able to use the SUMIFs without racking your brain too much.

Comment: @zaptask, Doh! Sorry you are right, both of those should be 100.

Comment: @dev1998, Thanks, I'm trying to avoid VBA if possible, I'm really hoping there would be some form of lookup coupled with SUMIF that could help...

Comment: I think @devuxer has provided a pretty good solution. I don't think you can  get a formula solution without a helper column either. Take a look at it and if it works for you then be sure to select it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to do this entirely with formulas and no helper column. I came up with a solution that uses formulas and just one helper column.

Given the sheet is set up like this...

[image]

...you would need to do the following:

- Enter `=OR(COUNTIF(A$2:A$7,A2)=1,B2="Actual")` into I2
- Copy the formula down to cover all items
- Enter `=SUMIF($I2:$I7,TRUE,C2:C7)` into C9
- Copy the formula to the right to cover all weeks

The formula in I2 counts the number of items that match the current item. If there is a total of one *or* there is a total two but the current one is "Actual", then it puts `TRUE`, otherwise it puts `FALSE`. (I'm assuming here that you only have one "Forecast" and one "Actual" per item. If that's not the case, please let me know.)

With this helper column, the `SUMIF` formula is quite straightforward--it simply adds up the values that for that week that have a `TRUE` in column I.

**Helper column on separate worksheet**

If you absolutely can't put a helper formula on Sheet1 (or whatever the name of your sheet is), you could add a new sheet (Sheet2) and place the helper column on that sheet instead. In that case, you would need to do the following:

- Enter `=OR(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A$2:A$7,Sheet1!A2)=1,Sheet1!B2="Actual"))` into Sheet 2, A2 (replace Sheet1 with the name of your existing sheet)
- Copy the formula down to cover all items
- Enter `=SUMIF(Sheet2!$A2:$A7,TRUE,C2:C7)` into C9 (replace Sheet2 with the name of your new sheet)
- Copy the formula to the right to cover all weeks

Comment: Clever, thank you! I should of said I don't want a tonne of helper columns, but one is perfectly fine. Thank you for your time spent helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it without helper columns.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,$A$2:$A$5,C2:C5,"")+($B$2:$B$5="Actual")>0)*1,C2:C5)
```

Confirm with ctrl+alt+enter

This is formula for Week1 i.e. cell C7.